# Is there a way to hide/grey out the Woocommerce "place order" button until the person enters a valid coupon code?

Tags: woocommerce

I am building a microsite for a company. They are running a promotion for current/former customers which allows a person to redeem an offer for a free single product using a coupon code. Is there a way to keep a person from checking out until the person enters the valid coupon code? It's a free product so there is no conditional payment or anything.

I cannot find a plugin that does this and I tried a string of code from a different stackover flow similar question but that code did not work (and no one answered that question).